# Creating pivot table in Python then exporting to excel

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pywin32, win32com

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a pivot table in Python and then export that pivot table with all its sorting properties into excel. Note I don't want just to values to be exported, but the entire pivot table with all its properties.

So when I go to the exported excel pivot table, I can still see its report filter, column label, row labels, and field list. It should be as if I manually created the pivot table.

Comment: Since you added a Pandas tag to the question do you mean is is "possible to create a pivot table in **Pandas** and then export that pivot table "? If so that isn't currently possible with the Excel writers supported by Pandas.

Comment: When I tried it with pandas and exported it to excel, only the values were exported not the rules and macros that resulted in the table. So I want the exported excel to maintain all of the sorting properties which I can change at any time.